# XAML adding namespace for converters class

Tags: c#, class, xaml, namespaces

I'm getting "The name xxx does not exist in yyy" all the time.
I don't understand why, i think i tried all possible combinations.

All of my cs file, including main window are in "Web_Media_Seeker_WPF" namespace

**Converters.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Web_Media_Seeker_WPF.WPFConverters
{
    public class BoolToValueConverter<T> : IValueConverter
    {
        public T FalseValue { get; set; }
        public T TrueValue { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return FalseValue;
            else
                return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value != null ? value.Equals(TrueValue) : false;
        }
    }

    public class BoolToObjectConverter : BoolToValueConverter<Object> { }
    public class BoolToStringConverter : BoolToValueConverter<String> { }
    public class BoolToBrushConverter : BoolToValueConverter<System.Windows.Media.Brush> { }
    public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : BoolToValueConverter<System.Windows.Visibility> { }
    public class BoolToColorConverter : BoolToValueConverter<System.Windows.Media.Color> { }
    public class BoolToImageSourceConverter : BoolToValueConverter<System.Windows.Media.ImageSource> { }
    public class BootToBoolConverter : BoolToValueConverter<bool> { }

        public class AddValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            object result = value;
            int Value;

            if (value != null && targetType == typeof(Int32) &&
                int.TryParse((string)parameter,
                System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer, culture, out Value))
            {
                result = (int)value + (int)Value;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namesapce:Web_Media_Seeker_WPF.WPFConverters"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Class="Web_Media_Seeker_WPF.MainWindow"
        Title="Web Media Seeker"
        Height="563"
        Width="836">
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToImageSourceConverter x:Key="BoolToWorkImageSource"
                                      TrueValue="Images/work.png"
                                      FalseValue="Images/idle.png" />
    <local:BootToBoolConverter x:Key="InvertBool"
                               TrueValue="False"
                               FalseValue="True" />
    <local:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="WorkTooltip"
                                 TrueValue="Working..."
                                 FalseValue="Idle" />
  </Window.Resources>
and stuff...
```

Errors i have:

> The name "BoolToImageSourceConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namesapce:Web_Media_Seeker_WPF.WPFValuesConverters".
>
> The name "BoolToStringConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namesapce:Web_Media_Seeker_WPF.WPFValuesConverters".
>
> The name "BootToBoolConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namesapce:Web_Media_Seeker_WPF.WPFValuesConverters".
>
> The tag 'BoolToImageSourceConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namesapce:Web_Media_Seeker_WPF.WPFValuesConverters'.
>
> The type 'local:BoolToImageSourceConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
>
> The type 'local:BoolToStringConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
>
> The type 'local:BootToBoolConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an error in your namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namesapce:Web_Media_Seeker_WPF.WPFConverters"
```

should be

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Web_Media_Seeker_WPF.WPFConverters"
```

You put `namesapce` instead of `namespace`

Comment: I tried this. when removed project builds without problems. When i add them back i get errors again

Comment: Can you run the application? Sometimes VS doesn't get it immediately.

Comment: No, i get "There were build errors. Would you like to run last sucessful build"

Comment: Are they located in the same assembly?

Comment: Got it! you had a typo in your namespace declaration in the XAML

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem without the typo.
The problem wasn't directly with the XAML, or at least not completely. The original developer had named the Window tag with the same name as the code-behind class name, and that seems to be prohibited now. That was the only issue with the XAML. Everything else had to do with overlaps in the WPF and Windows.System.Data libraries that caused IValueConverter (in the System.Windows.Data namespace) to go unrecognized.
I first searched through the Object Browser for all libraries that had the IValueConverter interface. Of those, two were in my project, one as an afterthought because I thought I'd need it to replace elements of the WPF toolkit 3.5, which I removed. I deleted the one I thought I could do without, and that removed the issue. It's sort of an 'ambiguous reference' error but it doesn't come up that way.